# Browsers not seeing links in a multi-row list of states with in-page anchors on last row

Tags: html, css

I have a list of states on a page that breaks to two or more rows (using a row counter to insert a 
).  No matter where I set that break point the last row of in-page links do now work.  FF, Chrome, Edge - none of them switch to the pointer cursor and they don't recognize the last row of links.  I've tried wrapping at different points - no change.  It's always just the last row.  Viewing source is correct space/dot/space either.

[image: source code is correct]

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  In page anchors that were being referred to:

```
<div class='inpageanchor' id='NV'></div>
```

had this class:

```
position: relative;
border-top: 75px solid transparent;
margin: -75px 0 0;
```

I imagine that was to fix a scrolling with a fixed height top header, but that "margin -75px 0 0;" was not needed and was the culprit on the links breaking.